# Jquery custom validator - Check a value is valid or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have created a Jquery custom validator like this

```
        var response;
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "uniqueUserName",
        function (value, element) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/umbraco/surface/MemberShipSurface/ValidatePostCode",
                data: JSON.stringify({ PostCode: value }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.istrue);
                    response = msg.istrue;

                }
            });
            return response;
        },

        "wrong postcode"
    );
    $("#reg-form").validate({
    rules: {
        day: {
            required: true,
            range: [01, 31]
        }, 
        PostCode: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            maxlength: 4,
            minlength: 4,
            uniqueUserName: true
        }
    },

    errorElement: "span",

    submitHandler: function (form) {      
    }
});
```

If the output from ajax is true it means the validation was success and we do not need to show any error message else show error message. But right now What ever value i enter on the form first it is showing as wrong and from second time onward it shows validation success. Can anyone pl point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: declare this  `var response=false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [remote-method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) available you can use it like,

```
rules: {
    day: {
        required: true,
        range: [01, 31]
    },            
    PostCode: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      maxlength: 4,
      minlength: 4,
      remote: {
        url: "/umbraco/surface/MemberShipSurface/ValidatePostCode",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          PostCode: function() {
            return $( "#PostCode" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

If you want using custom method then use `async=false` in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) call like

```
var response=false;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async:false,// now it will wait until you get response
    url: "/umbraco/surface/MemberShipSurface/ValidatePostCode",
    data: JSON.stringify({ PostCode: value }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
        response = msg.istrue;
    }
});
return response;
```

Comment: This code is not showing any error message for what ever data I enter

Comment: What value you are returning in `msg.istrue`?

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
    var response= false;
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "uniqueUserName",
        function (value, element) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/umbraco/surface/MemberShipSurface/ValidatePostCode",
                data: JSON.stringify({ PostCode: value }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.istrue);
                    response = msg.istrue === "true" ? true : false;

                }
            });
            return response;
        },

        "wrong postcode"
    );
    $("#reg-form").validate({
        rules: {
            day: {
                required: true,
                range: [01, 31]
            }, 
            PostCode: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                maxlength: 4,
                minlength: 4,
                uniqueUserName: true
            }
        },

        errorElement: "span",

        submitHandler: function (form) {      
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not working. Same issue as i above stated happens again

Comment: whiat the value of msg.istrue?

Comment: If data is valid then true and if data is wrong false

Comment: can you create a fiddle?